# Graph Database and Big Data

Tags: neo4j, bigdata, projects

I've been working on a project that involves graph database and I used Neo4j as a tool. 
Since, I am on the verge of completing the project, I was thinking of integrating it with big data.
Is there any way of integrating or connecting them, any current real world examples which uses that combo?

Comment: Would this qualify? https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-mazerunner

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this blog post about Mazerunner for Neo4j: http://www.kennybastani.com/2014/11/using-apache-spark-and-neo4j-for-big.html

It's still experimental and installation requires a VM deployment. It uses Apache Spark and HDFS to run PageRank and import the results back into Neo4j.

More graph algorithms will be added over time.